# Help to understand result on divided differnece

Tags: numerical-methods

I am reading following Lemma. I am confused about determining the end points $a$ and $b$ as suggested in the lemma. If possible any numerical examples which uses this lemma will be enough to clarify my doubt. 
[image: Lemma]

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: It may help you to see this as a generalization of the mean value theorem.  when $n=0$, you have $a=\min(x,x_0)$, $b=\max(x,x_0)$.  And the statement says there exists an $\xi$ between $a$ and $b$ ( ie. between $x$ and $x_0$ ) such that $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

Comment: Let me remark that this lemma allows us to define $f[x,\dots,x]=\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$ ($x$ is taken $n+1$ times), which is useful in writing the Newton form of an interpolating polynomial with multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will suffice to demonstrate that the divided differences become derivatives at some point. Applying Rolle's theorem you can conclude the following statement:

Let $\{x_0,\cdots,x_n\} \in [a,b] : \exists \zeta \in(a,b) \Rightarrow f[x_0\cdots x_n]n! = f^{(n)}(\zeta)$.

---

Taking the $nth$ derivative of the $nth$ degree interpolation polynomial:

$$P_n(x) = f[x_0,\cdots,x_n] + \cdots + f[x_0,x_1]$$

With $f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ as the leading coefficient of $P_n(x)$. Then take the $nth$ derivative of $P_n$ that's why the factorial appears.

$$P_n^{(n)}(x) = f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]n!$$

Now as we initially know that:

$$f^{(n)}(\zeta) = P_n^{(n)}(x) = f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]n!$$

$$\frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!} = f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$$